# Подсчет элементов в масиве с нужным результатом в json

Tags: jquery, json

Здравствуйте.

Получаю ajax запросом json результат.

```
{"result":[{"title":"fhfhfhfhfh","type":"movie"},{"title":"hgfdhfhfd","type":"movie"},{"title":"dhgdfhgd","type":"movie"},{"title":"ddhfdhfh","type":"music"},{"title":"dhfhfdhf","type":"video"}]}
```

Как подсчитать сколько элементов есть, допустим, с type movie?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var res = $.grep(obj["result"],function(el, i){
    return el["type"] == "movie";
}).length;
```

Comment: Сколько новых функций в jQ.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {"result":[{"title":"fhfhfhfhfh","type":"movie"},  {"title":"hgfdhfhfd","type":"movie"},{"title":"dhgdfhgd","type":"movie"},{"title":"ddhfdhfh","type":"music"},{"title":"dhfhfdhf","type":"video"}]}
var res;
$.each(obj.result, function(index, value){
     if(value.type==="movie")
         res++;
})
```

или воспользоваться [underscore.js filter](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter)